# How can I disable automatic scanning for WiFi networks?

Tags: macos, wifi, macbook-pro

The objective is to strengthen the WiFi reception (at the moment without additional hardware).

I live in an area with a 100+ radio signals.
[image]

Majority is useless (to low signal) but still scanned and displayed. The one I get connection is so low it keeps lossing it if I sneeze.

Also I observed that my WiFi keeps scanning (looking for a Network) even tho I am connected.

Can I disable the continuos looking for a network? hoping to gain some signal strength on the one I am connected.

Additional information:
I have a MacBook Air with OSX 10.8.3, so no plugs for external antena that I know off. I live in Spain, and the routers are not meine nor accessible to me. Getting my private internet (ISP) is not a option.

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: Did you consider not clicking on the wifi icon and not running a utility that initiates a scan? The software doesn't run a scan unless you ask it to.

Comment: WOW, thats a good one, so it does not continues scanning in background!

Comment: It turns out it keeps scanning even if I do not look at it, nasty little sucker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to disable wireless network scanning. You can only disable the alerts about new wifi networks being found.

More significantly, because of the way wi-fi works, the transmission rate is going to be very very low due to all the stations interfering with each other.

But reading into your question at a deeper level, "How can I get decent wifi"

1. Google "pringle can antenna" You will find a raft of recipes for high gain directional wifi antennas.  This can be used to select a given station out of the crowd.
2. This, by itself leaves you leashed to an ethernet cable to the external antenna, which you really don't want to move.
3. So you connect the pringles cantenna to your own wifi router, set it to broadcast on a seperate channel (ideally >3 channels away from the one the cantenna is listening to)

Finally, you may find that the easier way to get anything done is to use a wired conection.

Comment: After it was edited, this answer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting up a wireless bridge and an new 802.11a ap?
Purchase a l-com 2.4Gz bridge and 5Gz Ap. All can be purchased here:

http://www.l-com.com/wireless-network-l-com-outdoor-cpe-wireless-access-points

Connect the two and use the 5Gz AP and your air to connect. The 2.4Gz bridge can accept a directional antenna to boot your target signal.

Comment: Great suggestion, can not get it in Spain :(

Comment: With my "millons" of wifi signals I think a directional antena is a must have, so I can focus on one signal. PS, I gave you cudos for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The way to stop the computer from searching for networks is to open network preferences, go to advanced and a small window comes up. Type in the name of YOUR preferred network, and delete all others and click apply.

The computer will stop looking for new networks.

Good Luck!

Comment: that does Not work. The scanning continues.